# Set the color in a choropleth based on the key

Tags: dc.js

I'm trying to set the color of a choropleth based on some properties linked to the key.
However, all the methods to set the color only have the value of that specific place, but not its key.

```
var map = dc.geoChoroplethChart(dom)
  .height(width*0.8)
  .width(width)
  .dimension(dim)
  .projection(projection)
  .colorAccessor(function(d,i){
    // it isn't the usual d={key,value} but only d=value
  })
  .colorCalculator(function(d,i){
    // it isn't the usual d={key,value} but only d=value
    //and it's deprecated
  })
  .title(function (d) {return d.key + ': ' + d.value;})
  // got the key,value as expected
```

how do I get the key from colorAccessor? it works fine from the other functions (eg title)

Comment: You're not imagining it: the chart really is passing only the value, and it's totally inconsistent; this is partly because it has both map data and crossfilter data, but mostly it was probably not thought out. Looks like you might be able to use `i` as an index into your geoJson as a hack to get the key?

Comment: Ouch. Do you think it's something that could be changed still in the api? it will be coherent, but break every choropleth ;( I'm checking with your hack see if I can workaround it

Comment: Yes, in fact [you reported this issue a couple of years ago](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/872) and it's linked to similar problems with other charts. Maybe the safest thing to do is change all of them at once and attach a console warning to them like we do when we deprecate functions. 2.1.* is all about fixing broken interfaces.

Comment: duh, ok, and workaround worked, I'm posting the code now, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaround I ended up using: 
create a custom reduce function that duplicates the key in the value.

```
  //the iso code of the country is the key
  var group = dim.group().reduce(
    function (p, v) {
      p.total += +v.total;
      if (p.iso == "") {
        p.iso = v.country;
      }
      return p;
    },
    function (p, v) {
      p.total -= +v.total;
      return p;
    },
    function () { return {
       total:0,iso:""
      };
    });

 var map = dc.geoChoroplethChart(dom)
  .colorAccessor(function(d){
    if (!d || !d.value.iso) 
      return null; // area without data
    // now d.value.iso contains the key, and d.value.total contains the value
    return colorIndex(d.value.iso,d.value.total);// do magic
  })
  ....
```

Answer (score 1):

so it turns out it's "normal". As suggested by Gordon, the solution is to map the index of the geojson with the data you want. In my case, I have extra data about each countries on a country array:

```
  var geojson=topojson.feature(europe,europe.objects.countries);
  // map index in the map to country data this hack is to solve a problem of not having the key on the colorAccessor
  var geo2data=[];
  geojson.features.forEach(function(d,i1){
    var i2=country.findIndex(function(c) {
      return c.country.toUpperCase()==d.id});
    geo2data[i1] = i2;
  });

  var map = dc.geoChoroplethChart(dom)
  ...
  .colorAccessor(function(v,i){
    if (geo2data[i] >= 0){
      //geo2data[i] contains extra values, eg 
      return v / country[geo2data[i]].threshold;
    }
    return v;
  })
```

Comment: Wow that's pretty painful, but I don't see how to make it better with the current API. Thanks for posting a workaround!